# Edit startup services for reboot?

Tags: boot, services

I'm trying to start openvpn and transmission-daemon on startup. But using:

```
sudo update-rc.d transmission-daemon defaults
```

does not work. They're in the start up services list. But they don't start on reboot. How do I get them to start on reboot?

```
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ - ]  bootlogs
 [ ? ]  bootmisc.sh
 [ ? ]  checkfs.sh
 [ ? ]  checkroot-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  checkroot.sh
 [ - ]  console-setup
 [ - ]  cron
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  dropbear
 [ ? ]  hdparm
 [ - ]  hostname.sh
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  kbd
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  lirc
 [ - ]  minissdpd
 [ - ]  motd
 [ ? ]  mountall-bootclean.sh
 [ ? ]  mountall.sh
 [ ? ]  mountdevsubfs.sh
 [ ? ]  mountkernfs.sh
 [ ? ]  mountnfs-bootclean.sh
 [ ? ]  mountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  mtab.sh
 [ + ]  network-manager
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ + ]  nfs-common
 [ + ]  ntp
 [ - ]  openvpn
 [ ? ]  plymouth
 [ ? ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  procps
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ - ]  rmnologin
 [ + ]  rpcbind
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  samba
 [ ? ]  screen-cleanup
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ - ]  transmission-daemon
 [ + ]  udev
 [ ? ]  udev-mtab
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ - ]  vsftpd
 [ + ]  winbind
 [ - ]  x11-common
 [ ? ]  xinetd
```

Comment: You might want to check what the `Default-Start:` is in `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`.  If it's nothing, try `update-rc.d transmission-daemon 2 3 4 5`.

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing in that file as-is. Should I add "6" for reboot to Default-Start?

# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6

Comment: No, init doesn't differentiate between boot and reboot.  6 is just shutdown.   Have you looked in the runlevel directories? E.g. `ls /etc/rc2.d | grep transmission`?  If there is a link there, it has been added as a service, but it is failing.  Various people seem to have had [problem getting transmission to run at boot](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=transmission+boot).  It must log somewhere, so if that link exists in `rc2.d`, try `grep transmission /var/log/syslog` to see if there's any info there.

Answer (score 1):

try rcconf. Make sure to run as root.

```
$ sudo apt-get install rcconf
$ sudo rcconf
```

It enables/disables start-up programs. Using it should be pretty straightforward. Up/Down arrow keys for navigation, space bar for enable/disable. Enabled ones have an asterisk inside the checkbox. Press tab, then enter to confirm selections.